# Problem saving array<object> in backend C# list<object>

Tags: c#, reactjs, axios

I have form with grid data table inside form and other fields outside of grid and try to save all this data into the SQL Server DB, but when i try Axios doesn't connect to backend service. I think problem is something about compability of Array with List. I don't know the correct way to do things.
Typscript Model is:

```
import { RepairDetModel } from '../../models/repairDet/repairDetModel';

export class RepairMasterModel {
    public repairMasterId: number;
    public autoUserId: number;
    public year: string;
    public repairDetails: Array<RepairDetModel>;
    public isActive: boolean;

}
```

Axios request

```
add(repairMaster: RepairMasterModel) {
        return axios({
            url: `repairMaster/create`,
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            },
            data: JSON.stringify(repairMaster)
        })
            .then(res => res.data.data)
            .catch(error =>
                Promise.reject(HelperFunctions.getErrorMessage(error))
            )
    }
```

And the backend Service

```
public int Create(RepairMasterDTO repairDTO)
        {
            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(repairDTO.Year))
                    throw new BusinessValidationException(ErrorCodes.REPAIRMASTER_YEAR_MISSING);
                var repairEntity = new RepairMasterEntity()
                {

                    AutoUserId = repairDTO.AutoUserId,
                    Year = repairDTO.Year,
                    IsActive = repairDTO.IsActive,
                    UpdatedOn = DateTime.Now,
                };
 
                int repairId = DataAccessService.RepairMasterRepository.Create(repairEntity);
                DataAccessService.Commit();

                return repairId;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

RepairMasterDTO class

```
    public class RepairMasterDTO
    {
        public int RepairMasterId { get; set; }
        public string Year { get; set; }
        public int AutoUserId { get; set; }
        public List<RepairDetDTO> RepairDetails { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: What is the error? 404? And, `Create` doesn't look like a controller action to me.

Comment: I fail to understand what is your issue here. Does the data arrive on the server and the field of `RepairMasterDTO` get populated successfully, except for the `RepairDetails` field?

Comment: Will the data of this RepairMasterDTO repairDTO be filled?

Comment: @Ergis Data didnt arrived to backend. Axios makes request but doesnt connect to backend

Comment: Crowcoder error is 400 [object Object]. When RepairDet array is empty everything works but when i have elements receive an error

Answer (score 0):

At first glance it looks correct, try adding a **[HttpPost]** attribute to your endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Could you show the exact error message? I would first try to use the same type for RepairDetails and RepairDetailsDTO, pick either List or Array.
Also make sure the properties on both are the same.